mongo replica set config rs.initiate suggest to use public ip or private ip
I am tring to configerate a mongo replica set using docker, but i am not able to connecting to it on external network and got error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo1.
Docker config
services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:4.4
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017"]
    hostname: mongo1
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - "mongo1_data:/data/db"
      - "mongo1_config:/data/configdb"

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:4.4
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27018"]
    hostname: mongo2
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    volumes:
      - "mongo2_data:/data/db"
      - "mongo2_config:/data/configdb"

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:4.4
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27019"]
    hostname: mongo3
    ports:
      - 27019:27019
    volumes:
      - "mongo3_data:/data/db"
      - "mongo3_config:/data/configdb"


initiate
rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:'mongo1:27017',priority:1},{_id:1,host:'mongo2:27018',priority:0.5},{_id:2,host:'mongo3:27019',priority:0.5}]})


setup docker on ubuntu and create replica set by docker compose.
